# CIM/WBEM Packages which Provide SMI-S Compliant Client APIs

Tags: wbem

How can I determine if a CIM/WBEM package e.g. OpenPegasus, OpenWBEM, pyWBEM, SBLIM provide
SMI-S compliant client APIs to develop and management application.

These all are CIM compliant but I could not find out whether SMI-S is supported.

And how can SMI-S client API support be included in a CIM Compliant CIM/WBEM package?

Answer (score 1):

Your question unfortunately is a "given all apples are fruit, how can I verify that the specific piece of fruit I am holding is also an apple?"... it's not an easy question to answer... unless you have a lab full of equipment to test the genome of the fruit before you... or purchased it from a reputable dealer and it came pre-certified as an apple.

CIM is the base protocol.

WBEM is a specification, based on CIM which lays out some additional specifics.

SMI-S is another spec, based on WBEM and laying out a number of additional specifics.

So from the start, OpenPegasus & OpenWBEM are not automatically SMI-S compatible... only through the creation of SMI-S compatible profiles & providers are they can be.

When it comes to determine if a SMI-S provider/api/etc is actually compliant with the specs, that depends on what your requirements are and how much time & money you have to invest.

Like many protocols, it can sometimes be enough to simply see if it works well enough for your purposes and test with different configurations from different vendors along the way... one way to do that is to attend a SNIA plugfest: http://www.snia.org/forums/smi/tech_programs/lab_program

Given that SNIA owns the SMI-S standard, they also have a program for verifying compliance with it: http://www.snia.org/ctp/ (though it like many standard based verification will cost some $$$).

Comment: Hi Brendan, could one use any of the WBEM/CIM clients and then findout supported profiles from a WBEM/CIM Server and then use those profiles for management of the SMI-S Compliant device? Also such a management software, if it has to work with a wide variety of SAN devices it must include the functionality to findout and manage everything that has been implemented by the SMI-S Compliant device which means one has to go through the developer's manual of all the SAN devices from different SAN Vendors to include support for such functionality?And Thanks a lot for your reply it cleared my confusion

Answer (score 1):

anukalp,

Any client which claims that it supports CIM operations should be able to do the profile discovery.

The clients which I am aware of :- pegasus client, Java client from sblim project are all capable of this.

As a starting point, you should enumerate the RegisteredProfiles in the interop namespace and then follow the CIM_ElementConformsToProfile association to reach the implementation namespace.

Hope this helps.